# LaTeX for Companies

Tags: package-writing, documentclass-writing

I work with a small company (10 people). I've been a LaTeX user for roughly 20 years. We have been trying to implement LaTeX as the primary document preparation system in our company with varying levels of success. The group of people who usually end up preparing documents (proposals, reports, invoices, letters, etc.) are all familiar with LaTeX.

We need to prepare documents that can be shipped both in PDF form and in printed form. The company has a standard letterhead (a header and footer) with which documents should be prepared. All documents go in this letterhead. The PDF is shipped on email. Then the same document is printed on pre-printed stationery and sent across, when required.

We started by implementing a package that will generate the headers based on a custom command in the document source (something like `\GenerateForPrint`). We used `fancyhdr` for this. Lately we adopted KOMA-script, because of the flexibility. While going through the KOMA-script docs, we figured that we were implementing this as a bunch of hacks that muck with things like page dimensions and margins. We have had problems in the past with our "package", which we now realise is because of these crude hacks we put in.

We want to understand the right way of doing this. How should the base template be? Should it be a package or a document class or? We want this "base template" to be version controlled so that improvements can be shared across the team. We do not want to put the whole thing in the preamble of the main document source.

Comment: your question is much to vage.  But to decide if you want classes or packages, make a list of *all* the documents you want to produce, and then consider how you want the preamble to look like, e.g. do you prefer `\documentclass{ourinvoice}` or `\documentclass[type=invoice]{ourclass}`  or `\documentclass{scrartcl} \usepackage[type=invoice]{ourpackage}`  etc.  Consider really all documents including edge cases.

Comment: KOMA is based on a weird theory of aesthetics regarding text ares.  I would totally ignore their practices in this regard.  Think of KOMA as "I want to create my own document class..." that has formed a cult following.

Comment: Version control ... asks for version control like using git, subversion etc. ?

Comment: Supporting Ulrikes comment, it may be useful to identify a small set of very specialized documents or classes or packages, which allow some variation e.g. by options, rather than coming up with one-class-for-everything. // From a practical point of view you may want to apply Object-Oriented-Analysis to better understand, and later implement, your needs. Look for OO-Modelling, which is a precursor of todays UML-approach (Rumbaugh, Blaha et.al, ~1992 !). Many times identifying a good object model is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

So basically your documents are usually in a letter format, correct? (Not the legal/letter paper size, but a real, old-school letter, possibly in A4 format. Correct me, if I am wrong.) There are multiple ways to do this, obviously.

How extensive und numerous are your commands? A package is basically just a collection of (La)TeX commands, so this might be an obvious choice. That said, KOMA letters (Are you using either `scrletter` or `scrlttr2`?) support so-called `.lco`files, which can be loaded at run time, like so:

```
\LoadLetterOption{myprint}
%\LoadLetterOption{myemail}
```

… which would import `~/texmf/tex/latex/myprint.lco` by default. This allows for a quick and relatively painless implementation of a coherent corporate identity. Take a look at this [commented example from Washington State University](https://github.com/komascript/notepaper-wsu/tree/main) to get an idea and get you started.